# Error al enviar formulario desde APP Java a PHP Verifying that you are not a robot

Tags: php, java, phpmyadmin

Una consulta, tengo una Aplicación Java (1.8) que envía y recibe datos a un Servidor Rentado con Mysql PHP (8). Ya tengo 11 años con ese servicio WEB pero últimamente me informan de un error al momento de enviar o recibir datos, el proveedor del hosting dice que el Servidor cuando detecta una actividad fuera de los habitual activa como protección un captcha, y los clientes al recibir la repuesta del servidor con HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity() reciben el siguiente mensaje "Verifying that you are not a robot..." solicitando resolver a Captcha para poder recibir una respuesta. Que se puede hacer para solventar esta capa de protección a Nivel de programación ?

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es la respuesta del Servidor al hacer una petición

---

Esta es la Respuesta que da el Servidor cuando se envía una Petición a formulario en `PHP` desde Java, pide el resolver el `Captcha`, eso se puede resolver vía WEB pero, en una aplicación java que hace la petición, como se resuelve el `Captcha` dentro de la `APP`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlP);
nameValuePairsP = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
nameValuePairsP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cuenta", cuenta));
        
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairsP));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: Pregúntale al servicio de tu proveedor. Cómo vamos a saber qué necesitas hacer si ni siquiera podemos ver de qué estás hablando?? No somos adivinos. No se puede saber cómo arreglar un problema si no podemos ver el problema.

Comment: El proveedor posiblemente ofrezca documentación sobre su API